# trying to append to a json file

Tags: json, file-io

I want to save some data about tweets in a persistent json file. I'm using `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator` to write the tweets to a file, which works fine when they are inserted all at once. My code:

```
JsonGenerator g = new JsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(jsonFile, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
for(Tweet t : list){
    g.writeStartObject();

g.writeStringField(ID_FIELD, t.getTweetID());
g.writeStringField(DATE_FIELD, dateFormat.format(t.getDate()));
if(t.isRetweet())
    g.writeStringField(RETWEET_FIELD, t.getOriginalTweet());

g.writeArrayFieldStart(HASHTAG_FIELD);
for(String s : t.getHashtags())
    g.writeString(s);
g.writeEndArray();

g.writeEndObject();
}
g.close();
```

Problem is, if I want to add another bunch of tweets to the same file, this function will overwrite the previous ones. I've been trying to keep the generator open instead of closing it every time, but it screwed up the process of writing in the first place. also, the API doesn't suggest any way of "continuing where I left off". No luck with other json streamers either so far. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if the problem is that you can't append multiple JSON objects to your output - then just open a `FileWriter` and make sure that the target isn't auto-closed after each object write.

For instance:

```
FileWriter output = new FileWriter("/path/to/file");

ObjectWriter jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT, false)
    .writer();

jsonWriter.writeValue(output, object1); output.write('\n');
jsonWriter.writeValue(output, object2); output.write('\n');
jsonWriter.writeValue(output, object3); output.write('\n');
```

Comment: For me that was working out, but I had to set AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET to false instead of AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT